# Can a PC connect to an Arduino for serial communication without installing the entire dev kit?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I'd like to send a prototype board to a friend pre-programmed and wired. Ideally they should just need to plug in the USB and connect to it over a serial COM port.

With another laptop I used for testing I had to install the full dev kit, sketch editor and all to get it working.

Can I somehow send just the portion of the kit that provides the COM drivers and not the rest? Is there a prebuilt install for just that portion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows in `C:\Program Files\Arduino` there is a folder called `drivers`, which contains all the drivers for the Arduino boards. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: And for OSX and Linux the driver is typically shipped with the OS already (though older FTDI boards may require a driver on OSX?  Anyone remember?)